# A problem with grabbing var value from getElementById

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a javascript tool to convert decimal number value to HEX.

```js
setInterval(
function tohex() {
var decimal = document.getElementById('result').value;
var hex = decimal.toString(16).toUpperCase();
  document.getElementById("hex").value = hex;
});
```

```html
<input type='text' id="result" size="4" placeholder="Decimal" value="44032"/>
<input type="text" id="hex" oninput="tohex()" size="4" placeholder="HEX"/>
```

When `var decimal = 44032;`, the snippet shows the correct result: AC00. The value of the text input is 44032 as well, but in this case the script does not seem to render the correct hex value. What is the problem here, and how should I edit the script to render the 'correct' result?

Comment: `document.getElementById('result').value` always returns a string, not a number. Calling `.toString()` on a string is a no-op and just returns the initial value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Convert the value to `number`.

`getElementById` is returning the value of the element, which will be a string. You are operating directly with that value, intead you need to cast it to a `number` type variable first, you can do that using the operand `+`.

```js
setInterval(
function tohex() {
  const decimal = +document.getElementById('result').value;
  const hex = decimal.toString(16).toUpperCase();
  document.getElementById("hex").value = hex;
});
```

```html
<input type='text' id="result" size="4" placeholder="Decimal" value="44032"/>
<input type="text" id="hex" oninput="tohex()" size="4" placeholder="HEX"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `parseInt`. document.getElementById('result').value returns a value of string type. `toString(16)`function expects a number. Ref [Number.prototype.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString)

```
var decimal = parseInt(decimal).toString(16).toUpperCase();
```

```js
setInterval(
function tohex() {
var decimal = document.getElementById('result').value;
var hex = parseInt(decimal).toString(16).toUpperCase();
  document.getElementById("hex").value = hex;
});
```

```html
<input type='text' id="result" size="4" placeholder="Decimal" value="44032"/>
<input type="text" id="hex" oninput="tohex()" size="4" placeholder="HEX"/>
```